# MATLAB R2014b switch back to old color scheme?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

[As announced, MATLAB R2014b adopts a new color scheme](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-changes-in-r2014b.html), which sort of replaces `red` with `orange` and `blue` to `gray blue`.

I would like to opt back for the old scheme. How may I do this?

**P.S.:**

If I am simply plotting dot, lines, and all that, I can just specify the color myself. However, this is not the case.

I am calling a **sophisticated drawing function**, which displays the heat map with the MATLAB color scheme. They used to be "`blue` for cold, and `red` for hot", and now they become "`gray blue` for cold, and `yellow` for hot". It is just counter-intuitive!

Therefore, to avoid modifying the function, I **would rather switch the whole graphics system back to pre-R2014b scheme**.

Comment: **Complete speculation as I have no access to test** I wonder if the command line switch to [access HG2 before release](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update#testing) will allow access to the now depreciated HG1... potentially adding the switch `-hgVersion 1`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The old default colormap is still available - it's called `jet`.

If you want to set the colormap for individual axes or figures back to the old default, you can do that with `colormap(figHandle, jet)` or `colormap(axesHandle, jet)`.

To change it for all your plots, try `set(groot, 'DefaultFigureColormap', jet)`. You may need to set that each time you start MATLAB, so perhaps you might want to put the command into a `startup.m` file.

However I'm not sure I agree that the new colormap is less intuitive; in fact there is quite a bit of [solid evidence](http://www.mathworks.com/tagteam/81137_92238v00_RainbowColorMap_57312.pdf) that it is much worse in some very specific ways. That's why they changed it. Your choice though...

Comment: Cool link! I had looked into the research behind perceptually distinct colors a while back after getting bright yellow in a plot one too many times, this is a great continuation :)

Comment: @excaza In that case, see also [this series](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/category/colormap/) of blog posts by the same author on the same topic.